# Convertir texto a elemento de lista desplegable en php

Tags: php, html

quiero convertir una cadena de texto separada por slash(es decir, / ), a un elemento de lista desplegable en php,me refiero a que cada texto separado por /, se convierta en un option que intento llenar a un select(lista desplegable). por ejemplo:

tengo este texto de la siguiente forma:

```html
Estados Unidos / Mexico / Republica Dominicana / Centro y sur america / Australia y nueva zelanda / Canada / Asia / Colombia / Puerto Rico
```

he intentado para que se vea asi:

```html
<option>Estados Unidos</option> 
<option>Mexico</option>
<option>Republica Dominicana</option>
<option>Centro y sur america</option>
<option>Australia y nueva zelanda</option> <option>Canada</option>
<option>Asia</option>
<option>Colombia</option>
<option>Puerto Rico</option>
```

He hecho de todo y no me ha funcionado, si tienen ideas comentenlo. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si adjuntas el codigo que tienes de php facilitaras la labor de ayuda a los usuarios. Un saludo :)

Comment: Muéstranos todo lo que has hecho.  También te recomiendo [te pases por el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es convertir tu cadena de texto a un `array` y luego recorrer ese `array` con un `foreach`.

Te lo explico paso a paso:

Para convertir un `string` a un `array`, yo normalmente uso la función `explode` de **php** la cual sirve para dividir un `string` en varios `string`:

```
$pizza  = "Estados Unidos / Mexico / Republica Dominicana / Centro y sur america / Australia y nueva zelanda / Canada / Asia / Colombia / Puerto Rico";
$porciones = explode("/", $pizza);
```

Y por ultimo solo tienes que recorrer el `array` que acabas de crear con un `foreach` ya que es un modo sencillo de iterar sobre `arrays`:

```
foreach ($porciones as $val) {
    echo "<option>".$val."</option>";
}
```

Puedes probar el codigo con esta herramienta: http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono. es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aqui. para la proxima ya tendre claro como formular las preguntas. gracias :D

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta el mejor agradecimiento que puedes dar es darle un positivo y marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: listo, gracias :D